# jQuery Validation: Validating based on selected radio button selection

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm trying to write validation rules using the jQuery Validate Plugin (http://jqueryvalidation.org/).

The following is what I'm trying to do:

I have radio button options asking the user whether he / she is bringing accompanying persons for dinner.

```html
<input name="accompanyingdinner" type="radio" value="Yes" /> Yes 
<input name="accompanyingdinner" type="radio" value="No" checked/> No
```

When the selection is "Yes", a dropdown box would appear, giving an option of 1 to 3 persons to bring along for dinner. Input fields, requesting for the person's name and meal option will also appear in a separate table.

```html
 <table>
       <tr class="accompanyperson">
        <td>1</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="nameOfAccomPerson1" style="width:400px;"/></td>
        <td><select name="accomPersonMeal1">
            <option value="">Select Dietary Requirements</option>
            <option value="none">I have no dietary preferences</option>
            <option value="Muslim Meals">Muslim Meals</option>
            <option value="Vegetarian Meals">Vegetarian Meals</option>
           </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

What I wish to do, under jQuery Validate method, is to check whether the fields of "nameOfAccomPerson1" and "accomPersonMeal1" is filled up, when the radio button is selected as "Yes". I also wish to check for the other input fields for nameOfAccomPerson2 / nameOfAccomPerson3", based on the number of persons selected in the dropdown box.

Any advice on how I should write the rules? This is what I tried to write so far:

```js
nameOfAccomPerson1: {
    depends: function(element) {
    return $("input[name=accompanyingdinner]").is("Yes");
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot use `depends` by itself.  It is a property of another rule such as `required`.

Comment: See:  http://jsfiddle.net/9hk7zyfo/